# $geoNear distance.calculated not working?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, geolocation, geospatial

I want to retrieve the values within the 20 km radius but I am getting also the values outside the 20 km. What I am doing wrong?

```
var gquery = [{ $geoNear:  {      near: {
                            type: "Point",
                            coordinates: [  -73.935242,40.730610]
                            },
                            $minDistance: 0,
                            $maxDistance: 20000,
                            distanceField: "dist.calculated",
                            spherical: true
                          }},

                          {$group:{_id:'$category', total:{$sum:1}}

                      }];

                          Experiences.aggregate(gquery,
                            function(err, result) {
                              console.log(result);
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

$maxdistance does not find coordinates in kilometers, rather in  <strike>radians</strike> degrees. So you'll have to convert kilometers from the radius in <strike>radians</strike> degrees.

Like this for example.

```
var radius = 20
var maxDistance = radius / 111.12;

Place.find({
  'loc': {
    $near:[-73.935242,40.730610],
    $maxDistance: maxDistance
  }
}).exec()
.then(...)
```

EDIT: This is in degrees and for 2d circle

EDIT 2: Ok seems like i was giving you an answer for 2d. My apologies.

In the [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) for $geoNear Aggregation it says:

> Specify the distance in meters for GeoJSON data and in radians for
>   legacy coordinate pairs.

Since you told me you are not using GEOJSON so You must convert the meters to radians in that case.

To convert Kilometers to radians is as simple as dividing it by the radius of the earth (6371 km)

This is how it should look like:

```
var radiusInKm = 20
var radians = radiusInKm / 6371 // Divided by earth radius in kilometers

var gquery = [{
        $geoNear: {
            near: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [-73.935242, 40.730610]
            },
            $minDistance: 0,
            $maxDistance: radians,
            distanceField: "dist.calculated",
            spherical: true
        }
    },

    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$category',
            total: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }

    }
];

Experiences.aggregate(gquery,
    function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Comment: Ok, what is the value 111,12 or it is just an example?

Comment: It's how you convert it

Comment: ok thanks, but I am using the aggregate functionality and I tried with that but it is not working with your example

Comment: Are you using GEOJson or legacy coordinates?.

I assumed that you were using coordinates.

[Heres](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) The Description of maxDistance in $GeoNear an it says:  

 
Optional. The maximum distance from the center point that the documents can be. MongoDB limits the results to those documents that fall within the specified distance from the center point.

Specify the distance in meters for GeoJSON data and in radians for legacy coordinate pairs.

Comment: Also, are you searching in a sphere or in a circle. I realised that thats for a 2d and is different for 3d.

Comment: Above the code "spherical: true" and I am not using GEOJson. I need to use aggregate because I want to use the group functionality to count, e.g. categories.

Comment: Ok I tried and in my console I can see following(the maxDistance is 0.0031392246115209545) : experiences.aggregate([ { '$geoNear': { near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 7.7982025, 53.129217 ] }, '$minDistance': 0, '$maxDistance': 0.0031392246115209545, distanceField: 'dist.calculated', spherical: true } }, { '$group': { _id: '$category', total: { '$sum': 1 } } } ], {})          As result I am still getting values outside from 20km its strange